# Laravel: Send notification to 1000+ users

Tags: php, laravel, loops, notifications

I have a Social Network type Laravel application where users can comment and follow each other, and subscribe a page/user to get notification whenever a new blog/post has been published by the page.
Suppose, 1000+ users has subscribed to get notification for a page. Now, whenever the page publishes a post, I should send notification to all users who has subscribed.
I have a table for notifications like:-

- user_id - the user who has subscribed
- page_id - the page who published the blog/post
- notification - the notification text (same for all users)

Basically, I want to send the notification to all users who has subscribed to the page. In laravel, I can use loop or chunk for all users to add rows to the database. But I want to know what will be the most robust way to send notification to users in laravel. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely consider looking into Laravel's Queue for this. It will give a fine tuned control over how many get sent at once, when they get sent and how to handle the case of failure. I use the Queue + Redis for a lot of very similar functionality. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues

Comment: One more question, suppose, thousands of users will get a same notification. What will be the best database schema for the notifications table. Should I add 1000 more rows with same data for all users? or there is any better way?

Comment: If the notifications are the same for each blast, but there is the possibility of sending more bulk notifications in the future, but with different content, I would use a many-to-many relationship between users and notifications. Either way you're going to end up with a lot of records, but hey, storage is cheap ;)